# Jquery - Hide / Show - "Session" problem

Tags: php, jquery, html

I use this links and divs on my site:

```
<p><a href="#" class="navlink" id="navlink_1">Menu1</a> | <a href="#" class="navlink" id="navlink_2">Menu2 |</a><a href="#" class="navlink" id="navlink_5"> Menu 3|</a></p>

<div id="menu_1" class="mymenu">
</div>
<div id="menu_2" class="mymenu">
</div>
<div id="menu_3" class="mymenu">
</div>
```

And this jquery to hide and show the menu.

```
$('div[class*="mymenu"]').hide(); 
 var current;
       var showMenu = function(e) {
    // read the id out of the clicked elements id ('navlink_ID')
        var id = e.id.split('_');
        $('div#menu_' + id[1]).show();
    // store this element as new current visible
        current = e;
      }

      // hide all menu elements
      $('div.mymenu').hide();
      $('a.navlink').click(function() {
        if (this != current) {
          // check if an element is visible -> hide it and show new menu
          if (current) {
            var id = current.id.split('_');
            $('div#menu_' + id[1]).hide(200,showMenu(this));
          } else {
            showMenu(this);

          }
        }
        return false;
      });
```

How can i modify this code, if i reload the page, then the last visible DIV is stay visible. (i dont want to use query string for this. I try with jquery session but not work..)

Thank you for help...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cookies would be the ideal way to persist your collapsible divs, [ShopDev](http://www.shopdev.co.uk/blog/cookies-with-jquery-designing-collapsible-layouts/) has an excellent tutorial on how to acheive the same thing as you are attempting to do, using the jQuery cookie plugin.

Basically you set a value in the cookie for each `div` that you want to persist and whenever the event happens you update the value in the cookie, e.g.:

```
$.cookie('menu_1', 'expanded');
```

Also you need to check when the page is first loaded the state of each `div`, e.g.

```
var menu_1 = $.cookie('menu_1');

if (menu_1 == 'collapsed') {
    $('#menu_1').css("display","none");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest pure JavaScript way: set cookie.